How can we construct a NFA that accepts the substring matches
By "substring matches" (I'm not sure how to call it), I mean a binary string $x$ (something like 0011...) for a string $u$ in a regular language $L$ and a substring $w$ of interest, where each 1 at index $i$ denotes $u$'s substring starting at index $i$ is $w$ (i.e. $x[i]=1\Leftrightarrow u[i:i+|w|]=w$. You would generally expect $|x|=|u|$ and $x[j]=0$ for $j>|u|-|w|$).
Here are some examples I can think of: the string $abaab$ and $w=aba$ would give a "substring matches" equals 10000 while the language $(ab)^*$ and $w=aba$ would give a "substring matches" equals $\epsilon$+00+1000+101000+...=(10)*00+$\epsilon$.
So now assume we have a NFA (or DFA) $\mathbf{A}=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ for a regular language $L$ and a substring $w$, is there a way for us to develop a NFA (or possibly $\epsilon$-NFA) $\mathbf{A}'$ that accepts the "substring matches"s?

From my current understanding of automatas (which is shallow, I am still learning these), I would expect to build the new NFA $\mathbf{A}'$ from the given $\mathbf{A}$. But I don't know where to start as these "0" and "1"s seem to contain "future" information about the original string, which I'm not sure how to deal with. I have tried incorporating these "future" information in states by augmenting the existing $q$ to $[q,p]$, where $p$ is a path from $q$ to $\delta(q,w)$, but that doesn't quite work out for me and I suppose that is not the right track anyway. Many thanks in advance.

I think a good place to start would be to construct an automaton that takes in pairs $(w,x)$ where $w$ is a word and $x$ is a "substring matches" and accepts if $x$ is the substring matches for $w$. Are you familiar with automata that read in multiple inputs in parallel?

@TomKern Hi, thanks for your comment, unfortunately I am not familiar with this concept. Can you refer me to a website or a book?

The concept is simple: at step $i$, instead of just reading in the $i$-th character of one input, the automaton reads in both the $i$-th characters of $w$ and $x$, merged together into a single character. This is covered in section 2.8 of Khoussainov & Nerode "Automata Theory and its Applications". You'll want your automaton to simultaneously check that $w$ is accepted by $A$ and that $x$ is the substring matches of $w$. You can read about merging two automata together like this in section 2.3.

Thank you very much~ I will read and see if I understands this idea

Could you explain how you define the "substring matches" for a language $L$? Is it the union of all substring matches of all the words $u$ in $L$? I am confused by your example. The language $(a + b)^*$ contains $aba$ and the substring match of $aba$ against $aba$ seems to be $100$. However, $100$ is not in $(0 + 01)^*00$. Did I miss something ?

@J.-E.Pin sorry, I think my example was wrong, I edited it to be consistent with the definition.

You could first build a sequential automaton that outputs the "substring matches". Here is an example for the word $aba$. The vertical bars are just separators between the input (in red) and the output (in blue).
$\hskip 80pt$
For instance, on the input $baababaabbaba$, you would get the following path
$$
1 \xrightarrow{\color{red}b \mid \color{blue}0} 1
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}a \mid \color{blue}\varepsilon} 2
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}a \mid \color{blue}0} 2
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}b \mid \color{blue}\varepsilon} 3
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}a \mid \color{blue}1} 4
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}b \mid \color{blue}0} 3
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}a \mid \color{blue}1} 4
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}a \mid \color{blue}00} 2
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}b \mid \color{blue}\varepsilon} 3
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}b \mid \color{blue}000} 1
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}a \mid \color{blue}\varepsilon} 2
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}b \mid \color{blue}\varepsilon} 3
  \xrightarrow{\color{red}a \mid \color{blue}1} 4   \xrightarrow{\color{blue}00}
$$
producing the output ${\color{blue} 001010000000100}$.
Now, you can read the language $L$ in your sequential automaton to get a regular expression for the set of "substring matches" for $L$.
